# CNAME record points to foreign domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

Could I set in route53 that record abc.mydomainname.com points to some foreign domain e.g. google.com?

Currently, I am pointing from [www.mydomainname.com](http://www.mydomainname.com) to mydomainname.com and it is works.

Best,

Comment: Yes, that's entirely possible.

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is entirely possible, a `CNAME` record simply is allowing DNS resolution to route to that domain.

It is important that the target application will need to be able to serve traffic based on the domain that you have added in your Route 53. Without this, whilst your domain will route correctly it may have traffic denied from the application servers.